# Access Swarm content from a smart contract

Tags: contract-design, evm, swarm, ens

Right now there is no instruction in the Ethereum VM to access resources stored on Swarm. Is there a plan to add such a feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a feature (interpreted literally as access to content) is impossible for the same reason as random number generation, generic web access or system time: the VM has to be fully deterministic black box, executing exactly the same way in all nodes processing transactions.

However, indirect 'access' will be possible in a similar way to btc relay:
Indirect here means that a transaction can assert a certain content on swarm which you can challenge.

All we need to believe is that it is possible to prove that a byte sequence with offset `o` and length `l` is indeed part of a document 
at time `t` under a url `u` (say for instance `mydomain/path/to/my/content`)

the steps for this:

1. you can prove that at block `b` corresponding to time `t` ENS registry shows hash `h` as the resolution of `mydomain`.
2. you can prove that `h` is the root hash of a manifest (cascade of manifests) in which `path/to/my/content` points to hash `h0`.
3. you can prove that `h0` is the root hash of a document which contains chunk `c` (or series of chunks `c0,.. cn`) spanning over the challenged substring.
4. you can prove that the challenged substring is (or is not) at the relevant offset
5. you can 'prove' that at the relevant time `t` chunk c had an unchallanged receipt (valid proof of custody).

swarm will use proof friendly manifest format and a solidity friendly 32-byte segment-based binary merkle tree as the base hash for the swarm hash. This means that such proofs are logarithmic in the size of the document-collection under the manifest plus the size of the document under the url (disregarding the historical state proof complication in 1).

step 5 is a slightly different flavour of 'proof' than the rest since it asserts the actual availability of the information in question.